# How can i share base code between rails projects with git?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I want to share (and keep updated) some base code between my rails projects with git. How can i do?

Comment: The best description I have seen is this [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/96).

Answer (score 5):

You can use [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule), for example like [this](http://woss.name/2008/04/09/using-git-submodules-to-track-vendorrails/)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use submodules. They are ugly, hard to understand and to maintain. Much better is to use subtrees.

Git subtree is a part of GIT since 1.7.11 and I wrote an article about sharing code between Rails applications: http://igor-alexandrov.github.com/blog/2013/03/28/using-git-subtree-to-share-code-between-rails-applications/

In short: yes git-subtree works and works great!